# IndexError: tuple index out of range when creating PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I want to create test data in a pyspark dataframe but I always get the same "tuple index out of range" error. I do not get this error when reading a csv. Would appreciate any thoughts on why I'm getting this error.

The first thing I tried was create a pandas dataframe and convert it to a pyspark dataframe:

```
columns = ["id","col_"]
data = [("1", "blue"), ("2", "green"), 
        ("3", "purple"), ("4", "red"), 
        ("5", "yellow")]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)

sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(df)
sparkdf.show()
```

output:

```
PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

I get the same error if I try to create the dataframe from RDD per [SparkbyExamples.com](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/different-ways-to-create-dataframe-in-pyspark/) instructions:

```
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(*columns)
sparkdf.show()
```

I also tried the following and got the same error:

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
df1 = ps.from_pandas(df)
```

Here is the full error when running the above code:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\serializers.py:458, in CloudPickleSerializer.dumps(self, obj)
    457 try:
--> 458     return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, pickle_protocol)
    459 except pickle.PickleError:

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:73, in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     70 cp = CloudPickler(
     71     file, protocol=protocol, buffer_callback=buffer_callback
     72 )
---> 73 cp.dump(obj)
     74 return file.getvalue()

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:602, in CloudPickler.dump(self, obj)
    601 try:
--> 602     return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    603 except RuntimeError as e:

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:692, in CloudPickler.reducer_override(self, obj)
    691 elif isinstance(obj, types.FunctionType):
--> 692     return self._function_reduce(obj)
    693 else:
    694     # fallback to save_global, including the Pickler's
    695     # dispatch_table

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:565, in CloudPickler._function_reduce(self, obj)
    564 else:
--> 565     return self._dynamic_function_reduce(obj)

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:546, in CloudPickler._dynamic_function_reduce(self, func)
    545 newargs = self._function_getnewargs(func)
--> 546 state = _function_getstate(func)
    547 return (types.FunctionType, newargs, state, None, None,
    548         _function_setstate)

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle_fast.py:157, in _function_getstate(func)
    146 slotstate = {
    147     "__name__": func.__name__,
    148     "__qualname__": func.__qualname__,
   (...)
    154     "__closure__": func.__closure__,
    155 }
--> 157 f_globals_ref = _extract_code_globals(func.__code__)
    158 f_globals = {k: func.__globals__[k] for k in f_globals_ref if k in
    159              func.__globals__}

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:334, in _extract_code_globals(co)
    331 # We use a dict with None values instead of a set to get a
    332 # deterministic order (assuming Python 3.6+) and avoid introducing
    333 # non-deterministic pickle bytes as a results.
--> 334 out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
    336 # Declaring a function inside another one using the "def ..."
    337 # syntax generates a constant code object corresponding to the one
    338 # of the nested function's As the nested function may itself need
    339 # global variables, we need to introspect its code, extract its
    340 # globals, (look for code object in it's co_consts attribute..) and
    341 # add the result to code_globals

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:334, in <dictcomp>(.0)
    331 # We use a dict with None values instead of a set to get a
    332 # deterministic order (assuming Python 3.6+) and avoid introducing
    333 # non-deterministic pickle bytes as a results.
--> 334 out_names = {names[oparg]: None for _, oparg in _walk_global_ops(co)}
    336 # Declaring a function inside another one using the "def ..."
    337 # syntax generates a constant code object corresponding to the one
    338 # of the nested function's As the nested function may itself need
    339 # global variables, we need to introspect its code, extract its
    340 # globals, (look for code object in it's co_consts attribute..) and
    341 # add the result to code_globals

IndexError: tuple index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PicklingError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [67], line 2
      1 rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
----> 2 df1 = ps.from_pandas(df)
      3 sparkdf = spark.createDataFrame(rdd).toDF(*columns)
      4 #Create a dictionary from each row in col_

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\pandas\namespace.py:153, in from_pandas(pobj)
    151     return Series(pobj)
    152 elif isinstance(pobj, pd.DataFrame):
--> 153     return DataFrame(pobj)
    154 elif isinstance(pobj, pd.Index):
    155     return DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(index=pobj)).index

File c:\Users\jonat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\pandas\frame.py:450, in DataFrame.__init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    448     else:
    449         pdf = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
--> 450     internal = InternalFrame.from_pandas(pdf)
    452 object.__setattr__(self, "_internal_frame", internal)
...
    466     msg = "Could not serialize object: %s: %s" % (e.__class__.__name__, emsg)
    467 print_exec(sys.stderr)
--> 468 raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)

PicklingError: Could not serialize object: IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the error. All above code worked perfectly fine with dataframe as output. And there is nothing suspicious in the code or sample data. Are you getting error for the above sample data?

Comment: yes, all of the above code results in the error. I have also added the full error message to the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After doing some reading I checked https://pyreadiness.org/3.11 and it looks like the latest version of python is not supported by pyspark. I was able to resolve this problem by downgrading to python 3.9

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this answer!! This problem was tearing me apart today, and I couldn't find anything else on the topic.
It's quite frustrating that the [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html#python-version-supported) say that the version supported is "Python 3.7 and above" when that clearly isn't the case...

Comment: Thanks! I got same error on 3.11. Just an update, today PySpark supports 3.10 and I succeed too.